# Angular binding nested data

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I'm trying something like this:

```
{{ whichItem.id1.subCategories[whichItem.id2].subCategory }}
```

But Angular can't see **whichItem.id2**. What's wrong with this?

Comment: can you provide your `json`?

Comment: `[
    {
        "category":"category1",
        "link":"link1",
        "expand":false
    },
    {
        "category":"category2",
        "link":"link2",
        "expand":false,
        "subCategories":[
            {
                "subCategory":"subcategory1",
                "subLink":"sublink1"
            },
            {
                "subCategory":"subcategory2",
                "subLink":"sublink2"
            }
        ]
    }
]`

Comment: Of course in this example **whichItem.id** returns index of an object... Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like **.subCategories** it type of **array**, and **whichItem.idx** is type of **object**, so you cannot get the array item by the syntax **anyArray[someObj]**. you need to specify numeric value: **.subCategories[0]** (consider use [_underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) lib)

Comment: **whichItem.id2** returns a number but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by my self:

```
{{ whichItem.id1.subCategories['subCategory'] }}
```